# driver: is there a sense specific to sound technology?

Tags: american-english

I need to an explanation for the following word :

the word is Driver , and the article where the word is written is about HeadPhones

Driver - in computer terms - usually means the software that you need to install to make a new device work properly , that meaning doesn't seem to be correct here , please check it , thanks .

---

With sound hole valves and professionally tuned drivers to allow for crystal clear reproduction of your music

--

Comment: See Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary (sense 7).

Answer (score 2):

In audio, a driver is just a loudspeaker cone (or other transducer).  If you had a 3 way speaker, for instance, with a tweeter, a mid-range cone, and a woofer, each could be referred to as a driver.  In programming, a driver is a software routine that controls a peripheral (such as a loudspeaker).  So you could have a driver controlling a driver.  (Disclaimer: I didn't consult authorities -- these are just my personal observations.)

Answer (score -1):

In sound systems, the *Driver* is the part of a loudspeaker that transforms the electrical signal into sound.